# Does anyone know of an international postdoctoral association?

Tags: postdocs, international, networking, professional-association

The number of postdocs is increasing worldwide. Because of their technical expertise and dedication, postdocs are rapidly becoming the backbone of most large science laboratories.

I am aware of institutional associations for postdocs, which are venues for networking, exchange of ideas, solving problems. At the local scale. 
Examples:

http://www.nationalpostdoc.org

http://jhpda2.jhu.edu

https://uwpa.wisc.edu

However many postdocs move from their original departments, and became international. And it is my impression that similar challenges are faced by postdocs around the world, and it is quite hard finding out how things are going with colleagues abroad. Especially on delicate matters, via cold emails.

Please, would anyone be aware of some international association where postdoctoral fellows worldwide could meet, and discuss their difficulties and experience?

Comment: Aren't you posting this question on it?

Comment: @arboviral Indeed I feel SE is the best place for the moment, but it would be so much better having a true association with files, outreach, true names and addresses, and possibly meetings in flesh.

Comment: Ah, I see. Normally this would be field-specific, and you mention science labs - are you really asking about a general postdoc association, or something in a specific field?

Comment: @arboviral I am asking about a postdoc association, like the ones in the links. They are typically interdisciplinary and local. I was part of one in my last job, and the association took effective action to fix an institutional issue over postdoc salaries (got to newspapers). I am searching for this kind of association in an international scale. Like 'International Association of Educators' but for 'Postdocs'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a great idea Scientist/Tommi but there's none yet that I'm aware of.

A lot of issues are common to different countries, but there are many important differences too. A good reason to look up your national/sector/discipline association, and a possible roadblock to the establishment of an international group.

In Australia it's the EMCR Forum*. They recently asked about similar international groups that advocate for and represent early and mid-career researchers and got a few bites: https://twitter.com/EMCRForum/status/950530138491400197

- full disclosure: I am deputy chair of the EMCR Forum in 2018